# How can I import an interop dll into actionscript

Tags: apache-flex, dll, actionscript, interop, import

Making an adobe flex ui in which data that is calculated must use proprietary functions from a dll.

How can I import this dll into actionscript?

Is this the only way to achieve my goal?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since flex apps run on the flash runtime, you can't include anything that can't be run by the flash runtime.

What you could do is create a web service that can call the functions in the DLL and return the results in XML which you could consume from your flex app.